# Installing QGIS 3.26.x Buenos Aires ​on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, qgis

I try to install QGIS on Ubuntu following the tutorial of the website.
https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html

At the moment of installing QGIS itself, the following command is used:

```
sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

Then an error message appear:

```
Err:1 https://qgis.org/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 qgis amd64 1:3.26.1+36jammy
  404  Not Found [IP: 144.76.174.102 443]
Err:2 https://qgis.org/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 qgis-plugin-grass amd64 1:3.26.1+36jammy
  404  Not Found [IP: 144.76.174.102 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.qgis.org/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qgis/qgis_3.26.1+36jammy_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 144.76.174.102 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.qgis.org/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qgis/qgis-plugin-grass_3.26.1+36jammy_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 144.76.174.102 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

It seems that there are simply no QGIS distribution to reach with this command.
Would anyone has a working method to install QGIS on Ubuntu?

Comment: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton, unfortunately this tutorial is the same I have been following as mentioned in the question, and it is the one which is causing problem now.

Comment: then you should be downloading from `https://qgis.org/debian` not `https://qgis.org/ubuntu` or `https://ubuntu.qgis.org`

Comment: It is odd, as I am working on an Ubuntu system, not debian.

I am quite puzzled by the starting error message I have not seen before:

N: Ignoring file 'qgis-archive-keyring.gpg' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

But the following file is indeed the keyring downloaded with wget:

/etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it:

```
# fetch the signing key
sudo mkdir -m755 -p /etc/apt/keyrings  # not needed since apt version 2.4.0 like Debian 12 and Ubuntu 22 or newer
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg https://download.qgis.org/downloads/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg

#remove all references to qgis from all files in (or below) /etc/apt/ 
cd /etc/apt/
sed -i 'd/qgis/' **/*.list
cat > sources.list.d/qgis.sources << EOF
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian
Suites: focal
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
EOF

sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

I'm still on 20.04 so I used `focal` you'll need to change that to what ever your system reports with `lsb_release -c`

Comment: Thank you Ian. I have tried your method and got several errors.

sed -i 'd/qgis/' **/*.list
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command

And the expression below is just opening a string with ">" on the left.

cat > sources.list.d/qgis.sources << EOF

Thanks nonetheless for your help!